# TFS Automated Build

Tags: tfs, build, installation

I have this enterprise setup: The Team Foundation Server is 2012 with Update 3 on it (no Build service/controller/agents enabled on it).

The Build Server has only VS2010 Ultimate with SP1, also with the Build service enabled and 1 controller and 4 agents on it.

I cannot run the build definition. I keep getting TF900558: This build process template cannot be run on build server -Controller. Upgrade this build server to a newer version.

As far as I read, TFS2012 Update 2 (I hope Update 3 as well) can accept build definitions from VS2010. What should I do next?

Comment: Isn't this just that you need to install VS2012 on your build agent (the machine with you build agent/s on)?

Answer (score 0):

As I read the error, you are using a 2012 build template on a 2010 build controller/agent. You can upgrade just the TFS part on the build machine, or use an old 2010 build template.

Comment: Can you be more specific ....how should I upgrade just the TFS part on the build machine? I setup the Build Service, controller and agent on 2010....just to accommodate VS2010 builds.On the build machine I'm suppose to do builds only up to VS2010.

Comment: You can use TFS 2012 Build Agent to build solutions using VS 2010 (the VS version and TFS versions are independent).

Comment: Initially I installed TFS 2012 Build Service/controller/agent on the Build Server. The problem was that installed the Framework 4.5 as well, and we don't do builds for 4.5 yet. I uninstalled and installed the TFS 2010 BS/Contr/Agent.

Comment: So your only option is to use a 2010 template. It was called DefaultTemplate.xaml or similar, while the 2012 should be DefaultTemplate.11.xaml: check for yourself as I do not have an old machine to validate.